# How to show dgv2 right beneath the row in dgv1 being edited

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

[image]I am trying to show a dgv2 on dgv1 but right under the row in dgv1 being edited.

I tried with this code

```
  Private Sub Purchases_CellBeginEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs) Handles Purchases.CellBeginEdit

    Dim Y as integer = 0

   For i As Integer = 0 To dgv1.CurrentRow.Index
            If dgv1.Rows(i).Index < dgv1.CurrentRow.Index Then
                Y = dgv1.Rows.Count * dgv1.Rows(0).Height + dgv1.ColumnHeadersHeight + 12
            End If
        Next
        dgv2.Location = New Point(53, Y)

  End Sub
```

I shows alright but when i go back to row 1 on dgv1, it stays where it is. Lets say i start to edit from row 1 and i get to row 4, and i want to make a correction in row 1, i want dgv2 to move back under row1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In which event are you calling that `dgv2` to show below the row of `dgv1`?

Comment: dgv1 cell begin edit. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this myself and found using the mouse y position (minus top of the form + 24) worked perfect.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEnter(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEnter
    mouseY = Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y - Me.Top + 24
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

I removed the if condition and it works perfectly

this is the code

```
    Try
        For i As Integer = 0 To Purchases.CurrentRow.Index

       Y = i * Purchases.Rows(0).Height + Purchases.ColumnHeadersHeight + 34


        Next

        itemlist.Location = New Point(53, Y)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```